# @font-face not working on other computers - with correct file links

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I created the font stack using the Font Squirrel Webfont Generator, and the URLS seem to be working just fine (I used the entire address to be sure.) Still not seeing the webfont on computers that do not have the font installed. So not the usual problem...any ideas?  Many thanks!

```
@font-face { font-family: 'NorthernSoul-Caps';
src: url('http://s471850234.onlinehome.us/wp-content/themes/xstore-child/fonts/NorthernSoul-Caps.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
src: url('http://s471850234.onlinehome.us/wp-content/themes/xstore-child/fonts/NorthernSoul-Caps.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
url('http://s471850234.onlinehome.us/wp-content/themes/xstore-child/fonts/NorthernSoul-Caps.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
url('http://s471850234.onlinehome.us/wp-content/themes/xstore-child/fonts/NorthernSoul-Caps.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
url('http://s471850234.onlinehome.us/wp-content/themes/xstore-child/fonts/NorthernSoul-Caps.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove coma in the end of last row (or replace it with semicolon):

```
url('http://s471850234.onlinehome.us/wp-content/themes/xstore-child/fonts/NorthernSoul-Caps.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
```